# Delete and Replace File Older than 7 Days

Tags: python, python-3.6, os.path

I want to delete and replace an Excel file with the same name if it is older than 6 days. However, when I assess the age of the file based off of [`os.path.getctime(file_path)`][1], the `getctime` value does not change after I remove and replace it.

I'm not sure if using `getmtime` or `getatime` will work because I will be modifying the file in the interim.

```
    import os #check existing excel file stats
    import time #find creation date of file
    import openpyxl #excel module
    import sys #to collect sys args from command line

    def establish_wb():
        file_path = r'C:\Users\cj9250\Documents\this_weeks_blue_stakes.xlsx'

        if os.path.exists(file_path) == False: #if excel file does not exist
            wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
            wb.save(file_path)#create it

        current_time = time.time()
        creation_time = os.path.getctime(file_path) #when file was created
        file_age = (current_time - creation_time)/86400 #number of days since
        print(file_age)
        if file_age > 6: #if older than 6 days, replace the file
            os.remove(file_path)
            wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
            wb.save(file_path)#create file
            print('new one')
        else:#if younger than 6 days use existing one
            wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(file_path)
            print('old one')

        return wb



  [1]: https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html
```

I ended up making a dirty fix for this by storing the document creation time in a random cell.

```
import os #check existing excel file stats
import time #find creation date of file
import openpyxl #excel module
import sys #to collect sys args from command line

def establish_wb():
    file_name = 'this_weeks_blue_stakes.xlsx'
    file_path = 'C:\\Users\\cj9250\\Documents\\' + file_name

    if os.path.exists(file_path) == False: #if excel file does not exist
        wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
        wb.active['a49'] = time.time() #record creation time
        wb.save(file_path)#create it
        return wb #end function?
    else:#if it already exists, give wb a value for upcoming var assignments
        wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(file_path)
        print('a file existed')

    current_time = time.time()
    creation_time = wb.active['a49'].value #when file was created
    file_age = (current_time - creation_time)/86400 #number of days since creation
    print('this is the age ' + str(file_age))

    if file_age > .0005: #if older than 6 days, replace the file
        os.remove(file_path) #delete the file
        wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
        wb.active['a49'] = time.time()
        wb.save(file_path)#create file
        print('made a new new one')
    else:#if younger than 6 days use existing one
        wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(file_path)
        print('used the old one')

    return wb
```

Comment: I think Linux and `crontab -e` are better suited for this. SCNR. You could go here and not read out the age of the file, but define the time of the script execution and the time of the overwriting of the file.

Answer (score 0):

since os.path.getctime deals with changes to the inode, this Could be due to the way inode is assigned.

On most of the file system if you delete a file and then create another file the inode freed by deleting the previous file is assigned to the new one(provided no new file is created between deletion and new file creation operations).

```
touch temp.txt
stat -c%I temp.txt
970724

rm temp.txt

touch temp.txt
stat -c%I temp.txt
970724

rm temp.txt

touch temp1.txt
stat -c%I temp1.txt
970724
touch temp.txt
stat -c%I temp.txt
970727
```

when you do os.path.getctime it gives the into about last time meta data is changed for the file. os.path.getmtime gives info about file content change info like read's and write's.

Note: It is not always possible to get the exact date & time of file creation all the time since change in file permissions can change the meta info.